# Problems with Huawei Phone

Tags: huawei-g520-5000

I have a Huawei Android phone with 512 MB ram and a 1.2 GHz quadcore processor with 4GB internal memory with JellyBean on it. For the past few days no game is running on it. I have tried Riptide GP2, Dead Trigger, World at Arms but to no avail. They install but when I open them they load 20-30% and then it comes back to the menu screen with a wheel rotating.

I thought it was a problem with my ram but I researched that RAM frees itself to run apps. I have 30-40 MB free ram so please tell me what to do as I am really annoyed. I know it has good hardware as its antutu benchmark score is around 14000.

I do not want to root my phone.

I've uninstalled many apps just to make the games work, but it didn't work. I would like to play these games.

Comment: Can you tell which exact phone you use? The model name?

Comment: 30-40MB of free ram is hardly enough to run a game.

Comment: i have huawei g520-5000 phone.
|

Comment: @edvinas.me i also think that it is enough to run a game.so what should i do to make it enough to play a game.and also ho wmuch is required to run a game like dead trigger.and will i be able to play it?isn,t 512 mb RAM enough?

Comment: @iknowitsme Your best bet would be contacting the developers of these games and asking what the minimum hardware requirements are. For example, according to the Riptide GP2's Play Store [description](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vectorunit.red), support will refund your purchase if they can't help you with getting the game to run: *"We GUARANTEE if we can't fix your problem we'll give you a refund."*

Comment: and also if anyone can tell me what to do in order to free more ram?

Comment: Android already manages RAM on its own fairly well by closing other background apps automatically if more memory is needed. Not much else you can do really.

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned in the comments, 512 MB RAM with 30-40 MB free might be insufficient for running newer, resource-hungry games.  Your version of Android (4.1, according to Huawei g520-5000's [specifications](http://www.gsmchoice.com/en/catalogue/huawei/ascendg520/Huawei-Ascend-G520.html)) already handles memory quite efficiently by terminating background apps when more RAM is required for games and such.

Your best bet would be contacting the game developers over e-mail and asking for help.  Many will provide some support, just be prepared to know how to extract and send over the phone's logs.  Some, such as Vector Unit (developer of Riptide GP2) even go as far as issue a refund if they can't help you with the problem:

Quote from Riptide GP2's [Play Store description](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vectorunit.red):

> • • CUSTOMER SUPPORT • •
>   If you encounter a problem running the game,
>   please email the device you're using, Android OS version, and a
>   detailed description of your problem to support@vectorunit.com.
>   We GUARANTEE if we can't fix your problem we'll give you a refund. But we
>   can't help you if you just leave your problem in a review.
>   For fastest support on most common issues please visit: www.vectorunit.com/support

Comment: hey!these games actually ran on my phone.i checked the free ram and it was round 130-180 mb.i do not how this amount of my ram was free.i guessed that i had some ram issues and i was true.so if you all can suggest some ways of regularly keeping my ram this much free.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is, that your phone is really outdated. In other words, too old to run these games. Even in previous days, the SoC on your phone, Qualcomm Snapdragon 200, is a low-end processor, as well as the 512MB RAM being a fairly small amount. I suggest that you should give up attempting to run those games, because even if they launch properly, they would run *extremely* laggy and will likely end up being irresponsive due to insufficient system resources.